# PHP Websites Source Code

Tags: php, web

I'm looking for PHP script samples of websites. I'm just done reading a text book on PHP and I want to check out some of the various implementations.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Search for "open source php" or visit an open source host like sourceforge.org

Answer (score 1):

I would first start out looking at solidly built sites that utilize a framework, see [Recommend a PHP framework...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625405/recommend-a-php-framework-for-new-php-programmer/2625421#2625421).

Next I would look at some of the open source CMS designs built on PHP. Namely [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/) and [modx](http://modxcms.com/). Both **will** be over your head if your new to programming in general but getting the feel for how applications are written, syntax style, etc is well worth it.

Compile a list of questions you have, *why are they using `self::`?*, *what's a constant*, etc and either google for the answer or ask here.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not new to programming so thats not a problem, I would like to see how a website is coded, as my background is in C++ I tend to treat a website like a c++ program rather than a script.

Comment: @kenshee I tend to use CodeIgniter to develop, you can see my [Git Repo](http://github.com/joshkehn/Ignited-Blog) for a [blogging system](http://github.com/joshkehn/Ignited-Blog) that I threw together. It's not the most complex thing in the world, but it would be (I think) a decent introduction.

Comment: Thanks for the link, its exactly the sort of thing I was looking for.

Comment: @kenshee: No problem. Feel free to email me if you have any questions about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty generic question, and probably fairly open ended. Technically speaking, since PHP is a Turing complete language it can be used for basically anything. OTOH, if you want specific examples of problems to solve, perhaps that would be a better question to ask. I'd recommend some problem that you find interesting, and learning how to solve that with PHP. For instance, say you want a site that generates anagrams of a given name. Or maybe you want a guessing game. Or a message board (phpBB is open source and an example of a popular solution). If you're looking for concrete examples and ask specific questions you're more likely to get concrete and specific solutions.

Otherwise you'll get answers about as generic as your question.